# PostgreSQL custom domain with trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Is it possible to create custom domain / data type and associate some trigger with it, for example hash password?

I will have for example `password` domain and if I set some value to this column, it will automatically hash that, so I don't have to create trigger for each table with `password` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that.

As the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) says:

> CREATE TRIGGER creates a new trigger. The trigger will be associated
>   with the specified table or view

This clearly excludes types and domains.  (Very logically: triggers are normally fired upon changing something - here you want to change a *column*, not the type.)

You should instead use a stored procedure to take care of your password column(s).  And personally I think the less places password are stored at, the better.

Comment: I agree.  in fact, storing a password at all is a very dangerous pasttime.  Better to store only the salted hash of the password since it is almost impossible to reverse engineer a salted hash.